# Nodejs and Postgres 'pg' package await keyword unrecognized

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am new to both Nodejs and Postgres. I am attempting to build a small node application using express to just connect to a postgres DB and do a simple query. I found this guide, https://node-postgres.com/, and have installed this pg package.

I cut and pasted the first block of code into my method, and it won't run. It is crashing at the following line. If I take the await keyword out completely and start the server, it runs, but the query doesn't work.

```
 await client.connect()
```

Comment: Follow [this article](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/) or [this one](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `await` keyword is new in node version 7.6. Try running `node -v` to see what version of node you're currently using. If it's less than 7.6, you'll probably need to update in order to use `await`.

Comment: The `await` became available by default since Node 7.6. Before that parameter `--harmony` could enable it.